# Debug Gridview that's binding 10 times

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The Gridview is within a update panel and has nested Gridviews within it. The page only loads once. The Gridview binds ten times.

Nothing in the code behind explicitly binds this Gridview. It binds on load via sqldatasource, then immediately binds again and again. How do you go about debugging an issue like this ? How do I see what's triggering the consecutive binds?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. Please be specific with the kind of technology you are using, etc.

It depends on how many controls on the page require it to be initialized. If you have multiple of such controls, what you are saying happens.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know it's vague but I'm looking for direction on how to approach debugging this stuff more than an asnswr to why it's happening. There doesn't seem to be any way of figuring out what's triggering the binds. Yes there are many, many controls nested within this Gridview. Its a few thousand lines long.

Comment: How do I know if a control requires it to be initialised? If it's nested within the Gridview does it require it to be initialised?